# Javascript command to get youtube player in fullscreen (iOS)?

Tags: ios, iframe, youtube, fullscreen, landscape

I need to display youtube videos in iframe similar to one in official Youtube app. When device is rotated to landscape, video should be played in fullscreen mode.

I use this code for embedding youtube videos, however I'm not sure how to force fullscreen mode in landscape:

> NSString* embedHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"

```
                       <html>
                       <body style='margin:0px;padding:0px;'>
                       <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'></script>
                       <script type='text/javascript'>
                       function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()
                       {
                       ytplayer=new YT.Player('playerId',{events:{onReady:onPlayerReady}})
                       }
                       function onPlayerReady(a)
                       { 
                       a.target.playVideo(); 
                       }
                       </script>
                       <iframe id='playerId' type='text/html' width='%f' height='%f' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=1&autoplay=1' frameborder='0'>
                       </body>
                       </html>", self.webView.frame.size.width, self.webView.frame.size.height, self.videoId];

[self.webView loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];
```

And I get this inline player:

[image]

which has fullscreen button. I want to trigger fullscreen from code.

**Is there any javascript command for switching from inline to fullscreen mode?**

Example:*Youtube offical app*
Portrait:

[image]

and landscape:

[image]

**How to achieve this?**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search/query a youtube video, check out GData to retrieve the video URL.

To play the video in full screen, I would extract the video URL from the javascript and use [XCDYoutubeVideoPlayerViewController](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController) to play it fullscreen.

Comment: I updated my question. I need both inline player in portrait and fullscreen player in landscape orientation - just like on Youtube official app.

Comment: @BojanBozovic did you ever find a way to do this ? I'm having the same issues as you were.

Comment: @BojanBozovic did you got the full screen landscape mode ?
if yes please tell me how

Comment: @Jessica Unfortunately, I haven't found a solution. Please vote question up - more likely that someone will respond.